# jQuery plugin for showing a DIV on hover

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a good jQuery plugin that I can use to show a DIV on hover of an item, similar to the way SO shows the Tag details (with options to subscribe, rss, etc.) when hovered on a tag.

Here's a sample:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just came accross this one this morning which I think looks amazing: [Hovercard](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/Hovercard)

Otherwise there are plenty of them with "complex" content and more or less customization:

- The famous and rich [qTip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#ajax)
- [clueTip](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/)
- [jquery tools tooltip](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html)
- ...

Comment: Here, here. Love this plugin!

Comment: +1 hovercard is certainly cool looking, thanks good resource for me too!

Comment: See how the 'hovered' text stays in place in the opened div. The killing detail :-)

Comment: Qtip was what I chose to go with. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery Tools: http://flowplayer.org/tools/

You would then simply make a tooltip like so:

```
$("[title]").tooltip();
```

Comment: thanks, looks promising. will evaluate this against others